# How to Copy Python Command (with python)

Tags: python, command-line, operator

I would like to copy the python command from operators in edit mode, but the "Copy Python Command" is disabled

[image]

Is there any way to copy the python command from these operators that don't have the "Copy Python Command" feature enabled?

[image]

Comment: Ctrl+C when the tooltip is showing seems to work fine

Comment: Thanks! but i would like to do it with python

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + c when tooltip is showing.